# How to save Php variable every 5 minutes without database

Tags: php

On my website there is a php function `func1()`,  which gets some info from other resources. It is very costly to run this function.

I want that when Visitor1 comes to my website then this `func1()` is executed and the value is stored in `$variable1=func1();` in a text file (or something, but not a database).

Then a time interval of 5 min starts and when during this interval Visitor2 visits my website then he gets the value from the text file without calling the function `func1()`.

When Visitor3 comes in 20 min, the function should be used again and store the new value for 5 minutes.

How to make it? A small working example would be nice.

Comment: Just use file I/O...have a set file like data.txt that you use to store the data. You can use the filemtime() function to determine when the file was last edited...if it was more than 5 minutes ago, run the function again, store the data, and you're good to go for another 5 minutes.

Comment: is the function user related?

Comment: why is the function costly? is it because of the size of the data fetched, the complexity of the query needed to fetch it or something else?

Comment: @ElzoValugi No, the function is not user related.

Comment: @msgmash.com  It is not correct to say costly. The problem is the responding times of the remote server, from where I get the data, are not really fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store it in a file, and check the file's timestamp with [`filemtime()`.](https://www.php.net/manual/function.filemtime.php)  If it's too old, refresh it.

```
$maxage = 1200; // 20 minutes...
// If the file already exists and is older than the max age
// or doesn't exist yet...
if (!file_exists("file.txt") || (file_exists("file.txt") && filemtime("file.txt") < (time() - $maxage))) {
  // Write a new value with file_put_contents()
  $value = func1();
  file_put_contents("file.txt", $value);
}
else {
  // Otherwise read the value from the file...
  $value = file_get_contents("file.txt");
}
```

Note: There are dedicated caching systems out there already, but if you only have this one value to worry about, this is a simple caching method.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to accomplish is called caching. Some of the other answers you see here describe caching at it's simplest: to a file. There are many other options for caching depending on the size of the data, needs of the application, etc.

Here are some caching storage options:

- File
- Database/SQLite (yes, you can cache to a database)
- MemCached
- APC
- XCache

There are also many things you can cache. Here are a few:

- Plain Text/HTML
- Serialized data such as PHP objects
- Function Call output
- Complete Pages

For a simple, yet very configurable way to cache, you can use the Zend_Cache component from the Zend Framework. This can be used on it's own without using the whole framework as [described in this tutorial](http://www.joeyrivera.com/2009/caching-using-phpzend_cache-and-mysql/).

I saw somebody say use Sessions. This is **not** what you want as sessions are only available to the current user.

Here is an example using Zend_Cache:

```
include ‘library/Zend/Cache.php’;

// Unique cache tag
$cache_tag = "myFunction_Output";

// Lifetime set to 300 seconds = 5 minutes
$frontendOptions = array(
   ‘lifetime’ => 300,
   ‘automatic_serialization’ => true
);

$backendOptions = array(
    ‘cache_dir’ => ‘tmp/’
);

// Create cache object 
$cache = Zend_Cache::factory(‘Core’, ‘File’, $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);

// Try to get data from cache
if(!($data = $cache->load($cache_tag)))
{
    // Not found in cache, call function and save it
    $data = myExpensiveFunction();
    $cache->save($data, $cache_tag);
}
else
{
    // Found data in cache, check it out
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Comment: there's also redis as a cache option

Comment: great solution, thank you very much. unfortunately I have to choose only one as the solution and at the moment I use the one of  @michael

Comment: @alisia123 No problem, this site is about sharing information for users in the future as well!

Answer (score 1):

In a text file. Oldest way of saving stuff (almost). Or do a cronjob to run the script with the function each 5 minutes independently on the visits.

Answer (score 0):

Use caching, such as APC!

If the resource is really big, this may not be the best option and a file may then indeed be better.

Look at:

- apc_store
- apc_fetch

Good luck!